# mongodb 3.4 $mergeObjects equivalent

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to merge an array of dictionaries into one dictionary. This can be done using mergeObjects from mongo3.6 onwards. But I'm using mongo3.4. Is there any way I can achieve this?

For example I want to change,

```
'object': [{'a': 1.0,
    'b': datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 4, 55, 0, 520000)},
   {'c': 'Cedric',
    'd': {'New': 'Carlos',
          'Re': 'Carlos',
          'Se': 'Carlos'},
    'b': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 15, 5)},
   {'f': 'Robotics, Inc.',
    'e': 'Aerospace',
    'b': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30, 8, 16)}]
```

to

```
'object': [{'a': 1.0,
            'c': 'Cedric',
            'd': {'New': 'Carlos',
                  'Re': 'Carlos',
                  'Se': 'Carlos'},
            'e': 'Aerospace',
            'f': 'Robotics, Inc.',
            'b': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30, 8, 16)}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Mongo version 3.4.4+ you can hack your way through using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/#objecttoarray-aggregation) to group the keys and use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to get the desired structure.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            "$unwind" : "$object"
        },
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "toArray" : {
                    "$objectToArray" : "$object"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : "$toArray"
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$toArray.k",
                "value" : {
                    "$last" : "$toArray.v"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : null,
                "objects" : {
                    "$push" : {
                        "k" : "$_id",
                        "v" : "$value"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "object" : {
                    "$arrayToObject" : "$objects"
                },
                "_id": 0
            }
        }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of documents in the collection on which you are gonna query is less then you can use $unwind. But one should avoid $unwind if possible as it is gonna increase the number of documents to be processed in the intermediate steps.

As the final result as given by you is an array of a single final object I think that normal object can be considered here rather than array of the object. And this pipeline should give what you are expecting with doing all the in-place transformation without breaking the document into further many more documents.

```
[ 
    { $project: { 
        object: { 
            $arrayToObject: { 
                $reduce: { 
                    input: "$object", 
                    initialValue: [], 
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", { $objectToArray: "$$this" } ] } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } } 
]
```

Or if you still want that final object to be in an array then you can use the following pipeline

```
[ 
    { $project: { 
        object: [ { 
            $arrayToObject: { 
                $reduce: { 
                    input: "$object", 
                    initialValue: [], 
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", { $objectToArray: "$$this" } ] } 
                } 
            } 
        } ] 
    } } 
]
```